# How to compare two elements of a series with different indexes

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have two series of integers ('high' and 'low') with the same length and I want to compare all values of 'low' against all values of 'high' which are in a position prior to the value of 'low' being evaluated.

All I can think is a for loop such as the following:

```
gaps = []

for i in low:
    a =+ 1
    if low[a]>high[a+1]:
        gaps.append(a)
        
print(gaps)
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to run what in Excel would run with D2<C3 and expanding downwards.

Comment: `series1 < series2.shift()`?

Comment: Please be explicit and provide a concrete example of your two series along with the matching expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what you mean?

```
low = [1,2,3,4]
high = [5,6,7,8]

for i in range(1, len(low)):
    if low[i] > high[i-1]:
        # whatever you need to do
        pass
    else:
        # whatever you need to do
        pass
```